Why can't the MinGW version of Git (Git for Windows) be called from MSYS2 Bash?
I'm currently learning how to use Linux utilities as part of my workflow via MSYS2 on Windows OS, and I learned (if my understanding is correct) that the Git which comes with MSYS2 is compiled with Cygwin, and therefore calls POSIX APIs as it runs, which MSYS2 has to emulate. This causes the Git that comes with MSYS2 to run "quite a bit slower", according to the MSYS2 website. I also found people on Reddit complaining that it's slow.
Meanwhile, the Git that comes with Git for Windows is modified (?) to only need the Win32 API and compile with MinGW, so it's faster as it doesn't need the POSIX emulation. I did some more research and found that the Git for Windows team wrote a guide teaching you how to install their MinGW version of Git inside MSYS2. But they also put a big warning right at the top of the page stating that this is not a supported method of using Git for Windows and might cause bugs.
Now the part I don't understand is, why does the shell that you're calling the executable from matter if it's already compiled? My understanding is that if you compile a program with MinGW, then it would always only have access to Win32 APIs no matter if you call it from Command Prompt or MSYS2 Bash, and if you compile a program with the GCC provided inside MSYS2, then it would always have access to POSIX APIs no matter where you call it from. So seeing as the executable provided by "Git for Windows" is already compiled, why can't I just simply call the Git for Windows executable directly instead of "installing" it in MSYS2 Bash (which is not recommended according to the Git for Windows team)? What confuses me even more is that the Git for Windows executable is clearly designed to work in both CMD/PowerShell and Bash, since Git for Windows installs "Git CMD" and "Git Bash" for you to choose one to use git in (I guess the executable somehow detects what shell it is running in and adjusts output line-endings accordingly?). Therefore it can't be a CR v.s. CRLF line-ending issue. Is it that the Git executable is dynamically linked to a library that it would fail to find if you called it from outside Git (CMD/Bash), or something like that?
I opened Git Bash and ran which git, and this gives me the path /mingw64/bin/git. Combined with the installation directory of Git for Windows, I assume the full path it's calling is "%PROGRAMFILES%\Git\mingw64\bin\git.exe" when I run git in Git Bash. I checked and there is indeed a git.exe at this location. So can't I simply add alias git='"${PROGRAMFILES}\\Git\\mingw64\\bin\git.exe"' to my .bashrc file and use this from MSYS2 Bash? What problems would this cause, and why?

All file selection to run is controlled by the path variable. Currently in msys2 you will have a /bin directory and, if I recall correctly, /mingw-bin one of which will hold the git you don't seem to like. Elsewhere on your system in, e.g. /Program Files/git/.... there is the git-for-windows executable. In msys, you can see what is in your path with echo $PATH. What you want to do is make sure the search for  /Program Files/git/.... appears before the msys git path. E.g. PATH="/ProgramFiles\ Files/git/...${PATH}" to assign the windows git at the front of the PATH.

That said, I've never see "slow" out of either one and I'm happy to use either. Make sure you really are going to benefit before you start changing your path around. If it all goes to heck, just log out/log in to reset the environment to your old path (if you don't want to just use brace-expansions to trim the new windows git back off the front of your PATH if that doesn't fix it. If you have Msys2, I'd just stick with that git, it will be the latest version and it will be updated with your normal pacman -Syu upgrades. (PS - python is a snake :)

I know how to configure PATH, I'm just wondering why the Git for Windows team suggests installing Git for Windows in MSYS2 through pacman and a bunch of other complex commands instead of the simpler solution of just configuring PATH so that calling git in MSYS2 calls the Git for Windows executable. That suggests the latter wouldn't work. If nobody knows why it wouldn't work, then I suppose I have to test it myself. I just assumed that the reason it wouldn't work is obvious.

Then all the additional configuring likely has to do with the native libraries the windows git requires that wouldn't be found by simply adding it to your Msys2 path. I've run both Msys2 and git for windows a long time. Use the Msys version in msys and windows version if not. Never really noticed the difference. I guess it makes it easier for IDEs if they only have one git to deal with. I don't use an IDE on most projects, so it has never been an issue.

All that "extra" config in your link is just about installing the pacman package for git-for-windows in Msys2. The changes are just adding the repository and then configuring the environment on the back end. That would be the way to go if you want git-for-windows installed inside Msys2 instead of what it comes with. Totally up to you. If you need it for performance reasons, then just follow the steps. If you can live with the native git Msys2 provides, then don't worry about it.


why does the shell that you're calling the executable from matter if it's already compiled?

It doesn't matter.

why can't I just simply call the Git for Windows executable directly instead of "installing" it in MSYS2 Bash (which is not recommended according to the Git for Windows team)?

You can, and this is what I'm doing in everyday work!
The simple way to do it is to add Git for Windows to the (system-wide) PATH, and then launch MSYS2 shell (msys2_shell.cmd) with -full-path flag to make it not discard the system-wide PATH, but rather append it to the MSYS2 one.

But why does the Git-for-Windows team suggest doing something else entirely if just adding to PATH indeed works? I looked through their "not recommended" tutorial and see that they are using the packman util of MSYS2 shell to install Git-for-Windows in it, then installing a package named mingw-w64-x86_64-git-extra that modifies the MSYS2 installation heavily (sometimes in ways that are tedious to undo). The package can be skipped if you want to keep your MSYS2 pristine, according to them. There's also a long list of the modifications that package makes. You mean they aren't necessary?

@ILikePython The idea itself could make sense (Git for Windows normally uses a separate modified MSYS2 installation, so it could be desirable to merge them), so I guess they explain this for people who get the same idea. "modifications that package makes. You mean they aren't necessary?" They are necessary if you install GfW directly into an MSYS2 installation. You don't need them if you install separately and just add it to PATH.

Oh, I see. So I guess the reason is something like: Git-for-Windows installs things that are necessary for Git to run correctly, so it would still run correctly even if you call it from a separate MSYS2 installation. But if you only install MSYS2 and Git-for-Win in it, then you have to explicitly install the necessary stuff it relies on?

So I guess the simplest way is to install both Git-for-Windows and MSYS2, and then add the location of the git.exe provided by Git-for-Windows to the PATH of the separate MSYS2 Bash shell.

@ILikePython "have to explicitly install the necessary stuff it relies on?" Yes, and it seems to modify a bunch of MSYS2 settings, something you might not want on your primary installation. "So I guess the simplest way is..." Yep.

I see, thanks for your help. You really are an expert on all things related to compilers and MSYS2
